# Stability of equilibrium points for a second order matrix ODE

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, stability-in-odes

Given an ODE
$$\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{Ax}$$
where $\ddot{\mathbf{x}},\dot{\mathbf{x}}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the symmetric matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&-0.5&0&0&\ldots&-0.5\\-0.5&1&-0.5&0&\ldots&0\\0&-0.5&1&-0.5&\ldots&0\\\vdots&0&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&-0.5&1&-0.5\\-0.5&0&0&0&-0.5&1\end{pmatrix}$$

How does one determine the stability of the equilibria?

Does it depend on the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$, as it would do if the ODE was $\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{Ax}$? If so, how would we compute the eigenvalues of the above $n\times n$ matrix?

Building on advice from the comments section: Let
$$\mathbf{u} = \dot{\mathbf{x}}$$
$$\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{x}$$
Then the ODE is reduced to a first order system:
$$\dot{\mathbf{u}} = \mathbf{Av}$$
$$\dot{\mathbf{v}} =  \mathbf{u}$$

Or, in matrix form:

$$\pmatrix{\dot{\mathbf{u}}\\ \dot{\mathbf{v}}}=\pmatrix{\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A}\\ \mathbf{I}&\mathbf{0}}\pmatrix{\mathbf{u}\\ \mathbf{v}}$$
From the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Stability_of_the_two-state-variable_case
we see that the system is stable iff all the eigenvalues of this new matrix have a negative real part.
So we wish to solve
$$\det\pmatrix{-\lambda\mathbf{I}&\mathbf{A}\\ \mathbf{I}&-\lambda\mathbf{I}}=0$$
Where do I go from here to find the stabilities?

Comment: I added the "differential equations" tag to your post.  Like your question, ***+1, endorsed!*** Cheers!

Comment: One can always convert to first order by introducing auxiliary velocity variables. In the process your question converts to a linear algebra question: if you build a matrix with these auxiliary velocity variables, do its eigenvalues have anything to do with the original first order part? But this is, to some extent, a pure linear algebra question now.

Comment: As for computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of *that* matrix (before the extension), it is circulant, so there is a standard way to do it that you can look up.

Comment: Just a kind of hint: matrix higher-order equations are (to some extent) similar to higher-order linear scalar equations: you also can try to look for solutions in form of $v \cdot e^{\lambda t}$. And such solutions would also be related to eigenvalues of $A$. Speaking of $A$'s eigenvalues, $A$ is a symmetric matrix where diagonal elements dominate others. So it has real roots (because $A$ is symmetric) and it is non-negative definite (due to [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)).

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how we can introduce the auxiliary velocity variables. If we were to substitute $\mathbf{v} = \dot{\mathbf{x}}$ into our equation, we'd then still have the displacement term to contend with. Why would we seek solutions of the form $ve^{\lambda t}$, and is $v$ supposed to be the velocity vector here?

Comment: @Will The usual method is to transform equation $\ddot{x} = F(x, \dot{x}, t)$ into a system $\dot{x} = v, \; \dot{v} = F(x, v, t)$. It's a matter of simple check that $x(t)$ that is part of solution of a system is also a solution of original equation and vice versa.

Comment: I've taken this advice and updated the original post. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Since $-\lambda I$ commutes with $I$, the determinant is the determinant of $\lambda^2 I - A$, so the eigenvalues are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A$. Now your original matrix is positive semidefinite, so it has nonnegative real eigenvalues, so the square roots include positive numbers too. So the whole system is not stable.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. So if instead our matrix $A$ had non-positive real eigenvalues, the eigenvalues of our new matrix will be purely imaginary. Does this then imply that every equilibrium solution of our original ODE is stable?

Comment: In the pure imaginary case, there's no general theory, all that you can say is that if the trajectory moves away from the equilibrium (either forward or backward in time), then the rate of that motion is subexponential. But it could still be, say, polynomial.

Comment: @Ian Why exactly there is no general theory? I think if negative eigenvalues have only trivial Jordan cells, the question is solved: the linear system would have only oscillations, no trajectories will go to equilibrium in forward or backward time. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Evgeny Actually I forgot that this is already a linear problem with constant coefficients, in which case you are right that it will only oscillate. I was getting mixed up by the situation of a nonlinear problem whose linearization has this property, in which case lots of weird things can happen.

Comment: @Ian Okay, I've understood :) By the way, there is an answer in general nonlinear case too: you can perform a center manifold reduction and study the stability by the means of Lyapunov functions, for example. It still requires plenty of work though.